# Submit a Form via AJAX and Return a Partial View - MVC2

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-2

Seems like there are a lot of ways to solve this problem.

Currently I make a partial view with a form like so:

```
<div id="container">
    <form id="some-form">
        <input id="some-text" type="text">
        <input id="some-submit" type="submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

then I hijack the submit with JQuery and do an ajax post and replace the form with another partial view:

```
$(function()
{
    $('#some-form').submit(function(){
          $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "/Controller/Action",
               data: {someVal: $('#some-text').val()},
               dataType: "html",
               success: function (result) {
                   $('#container').html(result);
               },
               error: function (request, status, error) {
                   alert('Oh no!');
               }
         });
    });
});
```

The controller would be like:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SomeAction(string someVal)
    {
        //Do something with text
        return PartialView("SubmitSuccess");
    }
```

### My Question

What are other ways to accomplish the same thing and what are the pros and cons vs what I am doing?

Is Ajax.Form useful?

Comment: Why do you say: `What I am doing doesn't seem like the right way to do it...`?

Comment: Change "right" to "intended".  I feel like I should be using Ajax.Form or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's wrong with the way that you are doing?  I've done it that way, and it works out for me.  It depends how reusable you need to make the process; you could use a DIV with a css class, and then create a JQuery plugin or widget if you need reusability.

HTH.

Answer (score 3):

Personally I use the [jquery form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/). It will make your code shorter. Also assign the action parameter to your form to avoid hardcoding it in your scripts.

```
<div id="container">
    <% using (Html.BeginForm("action", "controller", FormMethod.Post, 
        new { id = "some-form" })) { %>
        <input id="some-text" type="text">
        <input id="some-submit" type="submit">
    <% } %>
</div>
```

And then attach the plugin to this form to AJAXify it:

```
$(function() {
    $('#some-form').ajaxForm({
        success: function(result) { 
            $('#container').html(result);
        },
        error: function(request, status, error) {
            alert('Oh no!');
        }
    });
});
```

The plugin will automatically send an AJAX request to the action, using the verb specified in the method parameter and serializing the values of all input fields in the request.